# How to compare number of matches in list of lists in python and return non-matches

Tags: python, list, set

I have two `lists` of `lists` generated by `two association rules algorithms`.

I want to compare which rules are `matching` and which are `unique` in both 1 and 2 algorithm outputs and return unmatched lists of rules.

Here, Each rule is given in form:

`[['37', '49'], ['39', '40']]`- meaning `['37', '49']` implies `['39', '40']`

The lengths of lists can be from `[1][1]` to `[1][3]` or `[3][1]`. above is a `[2][2]` example.

Example of `[1][3]` -- `[['37'], ['40', '39', '49']]`

sample outputs of both list of lists:
[image: Main list of lists]

[image: sample list of lists]

The expected `output` is `unmatched rows` in `list of list1` and `list of list2`
Any ideas,

Thanks

Comment: if first row of first input and first row of second input doesnt match count them as unmatched!? is it so?

Comment: yes, each row in first input has to be checked in all rows of second input and return unmatched rows

Comment: what's wrong with using set intersection and complement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say a is list1 and b is list2, iterate through `a` and check is it is not present in b.

```
>>> a
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[3, 4, 5], [3, 2]]]
>>> b
[[[6, 4, 6], [2, 5, 7]], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]
>>> [each for each in a if each not in b]
[[[3, 4, 5], [3, 2]]]
```